# Получение вчерашней даты в UnixTime без учета времени

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
Имеется стандартная форма для составления отчетов.
На форме есть несколько quasar элементов для выбора временного периода.

Столкнулся с проблемой:
В 2 формах выбора даты (начальная дата, конечная дата) по умолчанию уже должны быть прописаны даты. Вчерашняя и Сегодняшняя.

С Сегодняшней датой все просто. Получаю текущую дату. Ковертирую ее в UnixTime

```
    dateEnd: new Date().getTime()
```

Учет времени тут только на пользу т.к. в отчет попадет актуальная дата\время.

А вот с Вчерашней датой немного беда.

```
    dateStart: new Date(Date.now() - 86400000).getTime(),
```

Если делать так, то я дату получаю вчерашнюю. НО время будет текущее, а не 00:00 вчерашнего дня.

Есть какой-то не костыльный способ получить "вчера" без учета времени. ?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так?

```
// 0 соответствует 01.01.1970 UTC+0
let Jan01_1970 = new Date(0);
alert( Jan01_1970 );
let Dec31_1969 = new Date(-24 * 3600 * 1000);
alert( Dec31_1969 );
```

Comment: Как вариант. Спасибо.
СтэкоОверфлоу волшебное место. Стоит тут задать вопрос и буквально в течении 10 минут сам нахожу ответ :D Хотя до поста мог биться нескольько часов над вопросом
Сделал Вот так :     dateStart: new Date(dateNow.getFullYear(), dateNow.getMonth(), dateNow.getDate(), 0, 0, 0).getTime() - 86400000,